# Roslyn, Inheritance chain breaks in GetDeclaredSymbol() with assembly reference

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Scenario is that,

**ClassA in current Project**

**ClassB in AssemblyB**

**ClassC in AssemblyC**

Class Heirarchy

```
ClassA:ClassB
{
}

ClassB:ClassC
{
}
```

And the analyzer Code,

```
var declaredSymbol = _semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol( type);
var baseType = declaredSymbol.BaseType;

while (baseType != null && baseType.Name != "Object")
{
  inheritanceCount++;
  baseType = baseType.BaseType;
}
```

When type is ClassA, it can detect ClassB as basetype and after that the chain breaks, for ClassB it can't find BaseType (which should be ClassC, residing in Assembly C)

Comment: Check for compilation errors.

Comment: Got the problem, my semantic model was not correct. It was not getting all  dll reference properly. Fixed this.